# My wordpress website not found after I amended coding at Index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I inserted coding below to my index.php in WP Root:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

It doesn't help to change my wordpress url but turns my wordpress to 404 not found. And I cannot access my wordpress admin, had tried login.php also the same.
I did removed the coding, but the website still remain the same.

Comment: Which `index.php` are you putting this code in? The theme's `index.php` or the `index.php` in WP root? Maybe you're putting it on top of the file at a point where the rest of the WP is not even loaded.

Comment: index.php in WP root

Comment: You shouldn't be editing the root's index.php. Try putting that in your theme's functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this one, [Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

It doesn't mentioned that you have to edit index.php.

You can try to clear cache after editing your code and try to reload again your website.